# Blomberg refrigerator making intermittent loud knocking sounds coming from the ice maker

Tags: water, refrigerator

Sounds and vibration coming from the sealed ice maker assembly in top left side of freezer.  50 seconds knocking, 10 second pause, knocking resumes.   When we unplug refrigerator and plug back in, the knocking stopped for 50 minutes before starting again.  When I unplugged and let defrost for 2.5 hours, and then plugged back in, the knocking stopped for 77 minutes before resuming.  Repairmen can't get here for 3 weeks.  Any ideas?and vibrtion

Answer (score 2):

Icemakers work by freezing the ice, then thawing the outside, rotating the ice out of the tray, and eventually dumping it in the bucket.

If the ice fails to release from the tray, the gears will make loud gridnging noise until you remove the ice from the tray.

Easiest way I've found to do this is to run a hair dryer pointed at the icemaker until the ice releases.  Longer term, it seems that something is out of adjustment on your icemaker.  You can also shut it off by pushing the bail up.

Answer (score 1):

An icemaker typically has a little gearmotor that pushes the ice out of the mold when it finishes freezing. Those gears are often plastic and when they wear, the teeth  start to slip and make noises.
[image]